How did you made connection with the device?
I cannot connect it with the device
Need a solution for connecting this device how did you able to connect this device with the node js
mine is not connecting can you provide step by step procedure how can we do that in node js

what is the device?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I need to integrate zktecho w-20 with node js how do i do that?
